# Как изменить и сохранить переменную при запуске

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как изменить переменную а объявленную вначале, закрыть идл и если запустить чтоб в а сохранилось переданное значение, такое возможно?

```
a = ()
def start():
    b = 1 + 2
    a = b
```

Comment: Сохранить это значение в файловой системе. При запуске считывать оттуда. Иначе никак.

Comment: т.е. создавать файл туда записывать и от туд считывать!?! по другому никак? абыдно ))

Comment: Грубо говоря - да.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохранение/восстановление данных в разных сеансах работы

Для этого существует специальный пакет *pickle* у которого два метода:

1. dump()
2. load()

Пример использования:

```
import pickle

data = {
    'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
    'b': ("character string", b"byte string"),
    'c': {None, True, False}
}

with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)

with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data_new = pickle.load(f)
    print(data_new)
```

Для Вашего случая это может выглядеть так:

```
import pickle

a = ()

def start():
    global a

    b = 1 + 2
    a = b

start()

print("До", a)
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(a, f)

a = ()

with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    a = pickle.load(f)
    print("После", a)
```

Comment: Чтот не получилось
import pickle

a = ()
print(a)

with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(a, f)
print(a)

def start():
    b = 1 + 2
    a = b
    
    print(a)
    return a
    
with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    a = pickle.load(f)
    print("a", a, f)

Comment: @Venus @ "Чтот не получилось" - очень информативно! :-)  Пытаясь понять Ваш неотформатированный код, я обратил внимание на две проблемы:

Comment: 1) Функция *start()* нигде НЕ ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ. Т.е. её действие == нулю.

Comment: 2) После выполения оператора *a = pickle.load(f)* переменная *a* опять примет значение *()*, которое она имела перед выполнением *dump()*. А что Вы ожидали увидеть в *print()*?

Comment: старт запускаю выполнение функции в ней меняется значение  и вот это значение надо передать в а! в а будет значение инт или флоат, в комменты вот как то так залетел код!

Comment: @Venus Пример для Вашего случая добавил в ответ. Обратите внимание на *global a*. Иначе *a* - это локальная переменная в функции *start()*.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранить переменную в текстовый файл, а потом считать его и записать в переменную.