# Как сделать, чтобы словарь не сбрасывался при выключении кода?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, сериализация, dict

Предположим, что у меня есть словарь.
Ключ и значение, я запрашиваю у пользователя. Но после выключения кода, если я хочу вывести словарь, то он оказывается пустым.

Можно как-то сделать, чтобы словарь не сбрасывался?

Comment: Что такое "выключение кода"? Если после окончания работы программы словарь сбрасывается, то это нормально. Попробуйте перед "выключением кода" сохранить данные в файл, например.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изменить и сохранить переменную при запуске](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089464/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: Есть афигенная штука. JSON называется. Покопайте в эту сторону.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для сериализации/десериализации объектов в Python существует встроенный модуль [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Благодаря этому модуля можно сохранять в файл и загружать из файла любые Python объекты (переменные, объекты классов, etc.):

```
import pickle

data = {"keys": "value"}

# сериализация
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

пример чтения данных из Pickle файла:

```
# десериализация
with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Хотя, если данные простые, то лучше, наверное, сохранять `json`, который потом можно посмотреть глазами и поправить руками при необходимости )

Comment: @CrazyElf, абсолютно согласен ) Просто я посмотрел историю вопросов автора данного вопроса и мне стало понятно с чем у него возникли проблемы...

Comment: Серьёзный подход! )